# error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am trying to open visual studio code in my wsl nevertheless i have this error below. How to solve that?

```
To use Visual Studio Code with the Windows Subsystem for Linux, please install Visual Studio Code in Windows and uninstall the Linux version in WSL. You can then use the `code` command in a WSL terminal just as you would in a normal command prompt.
Do you want to continue anyway? [y/N] y
To no longer see this prompt, start Visual Studio Code with the environment variable DONT_PROMPT_WSL_INSTALL defined.
/usr/share/code/bin/../code: error while loading shared libraries: libxshmfence.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: same here, docker image based on ubuntu:20.04. You can install that dep via sudo apt install libxshmfence-dev. In my case, even though no errors are shown,  when I issue code <dirname> nothing happens.

Answer (score 19):

I added the following libraries and seemed to spring to life somewhat

```
sudo apt install libxshmfence1 libglu1
```